Как вывести конкретное значение из класса в python?
Написал парсер с сайта coinmarket который парсит цену и название, но не могу вывести конкретное значение из класса, программа выдает мне сразу 10 значений из класса, но мне нужно одно значение(неважно какое, главное что одно), как его вывести?
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = b(resp, "lxml")
tbody = soup.find("tbody")
coins = tbody.find_all("tr")

for coin in coins:
name = coin.find(class_="coin-item-symbol") #(вот отсюда мне нужно только одно значение, а он мне выводит сразу все 10 значений)
price = coin.find(class_="sc-500f568e-0 ejtlWy")

 if name:
  print(f"{name.text}: {price.text}")


Напечатайте print(type(name))

... Чтобы проверить, является ли он экземпляром класса. Поделитесь сообщением об ошибке, так будет проще.

Если написать print(type(name)) получится
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 10 раз

if name.text == "ETH":?

print(type(name.text)) напечатайте

Нужно понять в каком виде данные, если список то взять необходимое значение, если текст то сделать срез и корректно обработать строку.
